# limits , need help

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

How would I go about finding the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (2^n-n^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (2^n-n^2)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (2^n(1-n^2 2^{-n}))^{\frac{1}{n}} = 2 \lim_{n \to \infty} (1-n^2 2^{-n}))^{\frac{1}{n}} = 2$$

Answer (score 0):

After taking logarithm with base $e$, it suffices to calculate:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\mathrm{ln}(2^x-x^2)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mathrm{ln}2 \cdot 2^{x} - 2x}{2^x - x^2}= \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mathrm{ln}2 - \frac{2x}{2^{x}}}{1 - \frac{x^2}{2^x}}=\mathrm{ln}2.$$

Hence the original limit is 2.

**Note.** We used L'Hôpital's rule in the first equality.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} (2^n-n^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} (2^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}(1-\frac{1}{\frac{2^n}{n^2}})^{(\frac{1}{n})(\frac{-2^n}{n^2})(\frac{-n^2}{2^n})}=\lim_{n \to \infty}2(e)^{\frac{-n}{2^n}}=2$. 
The idea is to regain the special limit=$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e$